# Putting a picture in a table of contents using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have recently started to learn HTML and CSS. To practice what I learn, I am building a site on my computer. Now, I want the main page to be a table of contents for the website with the links to the other parts of the site in two columns that are split by a picture in the center of the page. The code below almost works as it does set the two columns at the left and right parts of the page. However, no matter what I try, I can't get the image to stay in the middle of the page. I managed to get in dead center using a mix of the margin and width properties earlier, but it wouldn't stay in the center if I shrunk the page (I did still have the image set with display:inline, so that might explain it but it's the only way I have been able to get the columns and the image in one line). I have also tried different variations using margin set to auto and using float set to center.

How do I set the page to where I have a column of links on each side of the image and it is all in one container?

The code I have so far for the table of contents section:

```
       <div class="Table-of-Contents">
        <ul class="ToCLeft-Column">
          <li> <a href="About_Me/info.html">A Little bit about my life</a> </li>
          <li><a href="My_Family/index.html">This is my family</a></li>
          <li><a href="Mental_Health_Wonderland/info.html">On a more serious note</a>
              </li>
        </ul>

        <img src="images/try_science.png" alt="Test Center" class="Center-Image"/>

        <ul class="ToCRight-Column">
          <li><a href="My_Interests/info.html">My Interests</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact/Contact_Me.html">If you want to get in touch with me</a>
             </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.ToCLeft-Column{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
 }

.Center-Image{
  display: inline;
  width: 100 px;
  margin: 10 px auto 10 px auto;
  text-align:center;
 }

.ToCRight-Column{
  display: inline;
  float: right 
  }
```

Comment: Did you decide to not use `<table>`?

Comment: @srrvnn: one would hope so, since it's not tabular information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align the table to the center of the page,

1. Create a container outside table.
2. Add this to the table's css:  `margin : 0px auto;`

This will only align the table to the center of the page. To align the image to the center of  the table, give equal width to the two uls.

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HdNgJ/9/

Now building a page that looks neat even on page shrinks to the extent of a mobile screen is another game altogether. It is called building a responsive design.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm looking over my CSS now so I can understand what I was missing. I see in the preview that it works almost to what I want. I do want the columns and the image to remain fixed if the screen is resized in the browser. Is that a part of responsive design too?

Comment: I am trying to get the elements not to wrap when the window is resized.

Comment: Having the columns and the images fixed doesn't require knowledge of response design. Responsive design is writing CSS rules that behave differently based on the screen size of the client.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was going for :)

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.ToCLeft-Column{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
 }

.Center-Image{
  display: inline;
  width: 100 px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align:center;
  float: left;
 }

.ToCRight-Column{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
 }
```

i hope you have given proper width to all your columns.

Comment: Thank you for the assist. It almost, but the elements under the html are now rising into the table of contents. Even using <div> tags to separate them doesn't work.

Comment: give proper padding to the divs so that they will remain at your appropriate level